# Connecting to docker container via telnet

Tags: docker, port, telnet, .net-core-2.1

I have a `NET Core Console Application` which has a `socket` binded to a  `port`.
I have *docker*ized this application and i am trying to expose the binded `port`.
The program shows its output correctly  when i use `docker attach [instance]` .
However when trying to connect with `Telnet` i get the error:

**Error**

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 20001
Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8806: Connect failed
```

**.NET Server**

```
class Program {

    public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    public const int EXPOSED_PORT = 20001;
    public const string ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";
    public const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 1;

    public static ReadOnlyMemory<byte> CreateMessage(ReadOnlyMemory<byte>request) {
        Memory<byte> response= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Response from Daemon:{DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
        ///------code------//
        return response;
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args) {

        Memory<byte> buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(BUFFER_SIZE);

        using (Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)) {
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ADDRESS), EXPOSED_PORT));
            Console.WriteLine($"Server started at {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()} \r\nListening on port{EXPOSED_PORT}");
            serverSocket.Listen(MAX_CONNECTIONS);

            var client =await serverSocket.AcceptAsync();
            while (true) {
                int rxCount =await  client.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
                if ((char) buffer.Span[0] == 'x'){
                    break;
                }
                await client.SendAsync(CreateMessage(buffer.Slice(0, rxCount)), SocketFlags.None);
            }
        }
        ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer.ToArray());

    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","DockerContainerDaemon.dll" ]
EXPOSE 20001
```

**docker and build command script**

```
dotnet build -c Release
dotnet publish
docker build --build-arg Port=20001 -t  daemon  .
docker stop inst1
docker rm inst1
docker run --name inst1 -p 20001:20001 -d daemon
```

Running `docker -ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
f675c3e502ad        daemon              "dotnet DockerContai…"   5 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:20001->20001/tcp   inst1
```

**P.S** As someone pointed out i tried exposing with  both `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` from the `.NET Application`.  to no avail.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to bind the application to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1. This will solve your problem.

Comment: But why? I am not trying to access it from an external machine.For me it gets blurry here.If i am trying to connect from the `host machine` to a `docker container` is it the same as  connecting from a different `machine` ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian - note that Docker uses its own network layer and with some NATting, you can get access to the Docker container - atleast that is if you do not change any network parameters etc. For more information I can best refer you to: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/  
Also; I see that you telnet to a port that is not exposed by the container. Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by not exposed? I exposed the `port` in the `Dockerfile` i run`Docker -p [realport] : [container port]`, i `bind` it in my `application`.What else do i need to do to expose it?

Comment: According to the first lines of your question you telnet to 8806. Shouldn't that be 20001?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo .I am connecting to `20001` and it does not work.